# Graylog v1.1.1: Editing source IP Address to reflect the IP inside a time stamp

Tags: ip, redirect, ip-address, graylog

I wonder if you can help with the following query?

I have a client (Centos 7) server (IP 1.1.1.1) in my office that sends its logs to a Centos 7 Syslog server (IP address 1.1.1.2). The syslog server forwards its logs to a Centos 7 Graylog v1.1.1 server (IP address 2.2.2.1). The three devices can successfully talk to one another and are using default ports and configurations as far as I am aware.

My issue is as follows: the logs displayed on the Graylog server have a source IP address and gl2_remote_ip of my syslog server (1.1.1.2). I would like the source IP address (and even the gl2_remote_ip) to be that of the client server (1.1.1.1).

So far, I have looked at using extractors to pull an IP address out of the message field (shown below) and am currently in the process of writing a drool script.

```
facility local1
full_message <142>May 31 15:11:57 1.1.1.1 116: .May 31 14:11:52.321: %SYS-6-LOGGINGHOST_STARTSTOP: Logging to host 1.1.1.2 started - CLI initiated
gl2_remote_ip 1.1.1.2
gl2_remote_port 40331
level 6
message 1.1.1.1 116: .May 31 14:11:52.321: %SYS-6-LOGGINGHOST_STARTSTOP: Logging to host 1.1.1.2 started - CLI initiated
source 1.1.1.2
```

However, each time I try to use regex commands (which I tested using the website http://www.regextester.com/) Graylog gives me an error telling me my regex is faulty. I have read through Graylog documentation and as far as I can tell, the regex it uses should be prett standard, but can anyone tell me what kind it is?

This regex line should work, according to the tester:

```
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

So, in conclusion, can anyone help me pulling values from one part of a Graylog message and adding them back into another bit of the message?

I want the end result of a message to look like the following:

```
facility local1
full_message <142>May 31 15:11:57 1.1.1.1 116: .May 31 14:11:52.321: %SYS-6-
LOGGINGHOST_STARTSTOP: Logging to host 1.1.1.2 started - CLI initiated
gl2_remote_ip 1.1.1.1
gl2_remote_port 40331
level 6
message 1.1.1.1 116: .May 31 14:11:52.321: %SYS-6-LOGGINGHOST_STARTSTOP: 
Logging to host 1.1.1.2 started - CLI initiated
source 1.1.1.1
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, can anyone help with this?

Comment: So, in the end I solved this myself. I did not end up changing Graylog, I installed syslog-ng and implemented "spoof-source". This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

yum install syslog-ng

> ```
> cat syslog-ng.conf
> @version:3.5
> @include "scl.conf"
>
> # syslog-ng configuration file.
> #
> # This should behave pretty much like the original syslog on RedHat. But
> # it could be configured a lot smarter.
> #
> # See syslog-ng(8) and syslog-ng.conf(5) for more information.
> #
> # Note: it also sources additional configuration files (*.conf)
> #       located in /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/
>
> options {
>     flush_lines (0);
>     time_reopen (10);
>     log_fifo_size (1000);
>     chain_hostnames (off);
>     use_dns (no);
>     use_fqdn (no);
>     create_dirs (no);
>     keep_hostname (yes);
> };
>
> source s_sys {
>     system();
>     internal();
>     udp();
>     syslog();
> };
>
> destination d_cons { file("/dev/console"); };
> destination d_mesg { file("/var/log/messages"); };
> destination d_auth { file("/var/log/secure"); };
> destination d_mail { file("/var/log/maillog" flush_lines(10)); };
> destination d_spol { file("/var/log/spooler"); };
> destination d_boot { file("/var/log/boot.log"); };
> destination d_cron { file("/var/log/cron"); };
> destination d_kern { file("/var/log/kern"); };
> destination d_mlal { usertty("*"); };
>
> filter f_kernel     { facility(kern); };
> filter f_default    { level(info..emerg) and
>                         not (facility(mail)
>                         or facility(authpriv)
>                         or facility(cron)); };
> filter f_auth       { facility(authpriv); };
> filter f_mail       { facility(mail); };
> filter f_emergency  { level(emerg); };
> filter f_news       { facility(uucp) or
>                         (facility(news)
>                         and level(crit..emerg)); };
> filter f_boot   { facility(local7); };
> filter f_cron   { facility(cron); };
>
> #log { source(s_sys); filter(f_kernel); destination(d_cons); };
> log { source(s_sys); filter(f_kernel); destination(d_kern); };
> log { source(s_sys); filter(f_default); destination(d_mesg); };
> log { source(s_sys); filter(f_auth); destination(d_auth); };
> log { source(s_sys); filter(f_mail); destination(d_mail); };
> log { source(s_sys); filter(f_emergency); destination(d_mlal); };
> log { source(s_sys); filter(f_news); destination(d_spol); };
> log { source(s_sys); filter(f_boot); destination(d_boot); };
> log { source(s_sys); filter(f_cron); destination(d_cron); };
>
>
> # Source additional configuration files (.conf extension only)
> @include "/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/*.conf"
>
>
> # vim:ft=syslog-ng:ai:si:ts=4:sw=4:et:
> ```

and then

```
> cat conf.d/20-syslog.conf filter f_fiddling { facility(local0); }; log
> { source(s_sys); filter(f_fiddling); destination(fiddling); };
> destination fiddling { syslog ("77.75.109.11" transport ("udp") port
> (514) spoof_source(yes)); };
```